Best method to dampen inductive spiking from pulsing coil with MOSFET?
A simple diode works across the coil to lower the voltage spikes, but I ideally need a way to absorb the inductive spiking as fast as possible. I've heard a Zener diode across the drain and source of the MOSFET is good solution, but others have said having another silicon diode in anti-series with the Zener diode will work better.
Parameters:
I am pulsing a 38mH coil (16 AWG wire wrapped around a small tube) with a IRFB4115pbf MOSFET at 66.6v (3 lipo 5200mAH "50C" battery's in series).

What MOSFET rating, or is it an open variable as well? Are there any limitations like parts cost or required efficiency? How fast does it need to go and what are the coil parameters (L, R, Z vs. F, mechanical flux if reluctance driven, etc.)?

Do you have a spike only or a spike with an apparent ringing?

You have some element connected across the coil, the purpose of which will be to receive the coil's energy. Being an inductor, the coil will decide current \$I\$; it will be whatever current was flowing at the instant the coil was switched off. See this answer.
You can't tell the inductor what current to pass at the instant switch-off, but you can control what voltage \$V\$ should be present across the inductor as that current passes, by controlling the impedance in that path. For instance, by connecting a diode across the coil, you clamp that voltage to 0.7 V.
Power \$P=I \times V\$ is the rate at which energy is received by whatever is connected across the coil. To deplete coil energy as quickly as possible, power \$P\$ should be as large as possible. Since you can't change \$I\$, the only way to maximise \$P\$ is to maximise voltage \$V\$.
In other words, you must allow \$V\$ to become large, but not so large that it damages connected peripheral components, like the switching MOSFET or BJT. Obviously, using a single, normal, silicon diode, \$V\$ is limited to 0.7 V, and that would dissipate coil energy very slowly.
Using a Zener diode provides some flexibility, permitting you to choose what that voltage should be, quite precisely:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Of course we require Zener diode D3 to clamp when current is flowing upwards through it (reverse biased), which means it's connected "upside down" with respect to D1. In that orientation it would also conduct current bypassing the inductor, so to prevent that we also include a regular diode D2.
On the left, then, D1 will clamp inductor voltage to 0.7 V or so, and on the right the combined voltage across D2 and D3, when inductor current flows upwards through them, will be a little over 9 V due to the high current, 1.2 A initially.
Here's a plot of potentials \$V_A\$ (blue) and \$V_B\$ (orange) immediately after the switches open:

The single diode solution takes about 1.4 ms to dissipate the coil's energy, but the Zener diode solution takes less than 200 μs. The trade-off for the quicker system is that you get a larger "spike" voltage across the inductor. There's no way around this, you simply have to build a periphery able to withstand that, and/or limit the voltage spike to whatever the periphery can tolerate.

Ahh, makes sense now! I have another question, I've simulated the circuit in LTspice with components close to what I'm using. There appears to be some ringing at the source once the voltage drops below the zener diodes reverse breakdown voltage. What is causing this? Is there a way to get rid of it? (I've included a screenshot with the circuit I'm using in my post) One more question. It takes around 15 microseconds, for the coil to de-energize. That seems like a long time. Is the coil really storing that much energy?

@JustinOsgood the ringing is almost certainly due to the inductance resonating with parasitic capacitances present, such as the diode's junction capacitance, and the MOSFET's $C_{DS}$ and $C_{DG}$. There are things you can do, such as deliberately adding capacitance to increase the period of resonance, to be longer than the period it takes to deplete coil energy, or resistance to dampen those oscillations. That's a big topic in itself. 15us is not a long time, for such a large inductance. I had hoped that I had illustrated that your only solution to speed that up, is bigger spike voltage.

My mistake, I meant 15 milliseconds (15ms). The mosfet I am using has a max Vds of 150v. So I'm using a zener with a Vz of 130v.

@JustinOsgood Don't forget your MOSFET has a body diode, which would prevent drain potential falling far below 0V.

You are mixing up some equivalent solutions.
To collapse the current quickly you need to allow a high reverse voltage across the inductor.
A simple diode only allows 0.7 V. A zener from D-S allows Vsupply-Vzener. If the zener is lower than the MOSFETs rating, it will be safe (although the zener needs to be rated for the peak coil current and the total energy (which can be more than ia stored in the inductance because during turn off, current continued to be drawn from the supply).
A zener + Diode directly across the coil will work too; it dissipates slightly less energy.
To force the energy to be dissipated in the MOSFET, connect the zener between drain and gate of the FET; but you need a diode in series with the zener to stop it from preventing the FET from turning on. You also need to slightly limit the turn-off strength of the driver circuit for the FET.
